# A new user is missing their edit, comment, etc. links on their question

Tags: support, editing, comments, hyperlinks

I encountered yet another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75653/turn-off-gnome-shell-notifications-while-user-is-available) where the poster had submitted their response to my comment as an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75653/turn-off-gnome-shell-notifications-while-user-is-available/75660#75660). As usual, I directed them to add the answer as a comment on their question instead. However, when they still couldn't find the relevant link, they sent me [this picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/231/unledmdu.png/) showing that they have no links below their question besides the feedback link, thus making editing /commenting on their original post impossible.

Is this a bug we just found? Or am I forgetting some restriction on new users? The page on [commenting](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment) under privileges says there is no reputation requirement for commenting on your own posts.

Comment: That image has become 404 or is it EOL..^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is no bug. If you notice the reputation for each user differs. This is because these users aren't creating registered accounts, instead they are creating unregistered accounts. This happens if they sign on to a new computer or remove the cookies from their browser upon closing. As a result they have to continually enter their information into the bottom of the site.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As is evidenced in the above screenshot the user has the same email and username; however, they have different user ids.

I've merged these accounts but this is merely a bandage until they create a full registered account.

What you may wish to do instead is encourage the user to use the Login button at the top of the page to create a permanent account so they can take advantage of all the sites functions.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! It never even occurred to me that this could be the cause. I'll let iostream know.